# MAC OS X 10.9.5 - strange result with du command

Tags: mac, du

Looking for big files that I could delete in order to free up some space on my Mac (OS X 10.9.5), I came up with a big cache file: `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.coresymbolicationd/data` . It was about 8 to 9 GB in size, so I did some research and figured out it could be safely removed - in fact, that's what I did eventually :) .
I have rebooted my machine and then checked again that directory, and now the file "data" is much smaller:

```
# pwd
/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.coresymbolicationd
# ls -l data
-rw-------  1 root  wheel  102891520 Dec  2 17:11 data
```

Which is about 100MB in size.
What is puzzling me is that, executing a `du -m .` on such directory, it shows me that the directory is using more than 60GB of disk space!

```
# pwd
/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.coresymbolicationd
# du -m .
64953   .
```

Is there any trick here? Why the result of du is not reflecting (as far as I understand) the actual disk usage on that directory?

Comment: Make sure to look for hidden files. What is the output of `ls -la .` ?

Comment: Adding to Darth's comment, you haven't shown us that `data` is the only file in that directory.  There could be other files beside that one (even non-hidden) that would cause the parent dir to be larger in size.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, fellows. No hidden files, and the other files there are much smaller (unfortunately the space for comments here doesn't allow me to copy the output of ls -la, but you may trust me :) ).